# Python - Defining a chunk function to encode genomic data

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessor, chunks

I'm trying to encode genomes from strings stored in a dataframe to an array of corresponding numerical values.

Here is some of my dataframe (for some reason it doesn't give me all 5 columns just 2):

```
Antibiotic  ...                                             Genome
0       isoniazid  ...  ccctgacacatcacggcgcctgaccgacgagcagaagatccagctc...
1       isoniazid  ...  gggggtgctggcggggccggcgccgataaccccaccggcatcggcg...
2       isoniazid  ...  aatcacaccccgcgcgattgctagcatcctcggacacactgcacgc...
3       isoniazid  ...  gttgttgttgccgagattcgcaatgcccaggttgttgttgccgaga...
4       isoniazid  ...  ttgaccgatgaccccggttcaggcttcaccacagtgtggaacgcgg...
```

So I need to split these strings character by character and assign them to floats. This is the lookup table I was using:

```
lookup = {
  'a': 0.25,
  'g': 0.50,
  'c': 0.75,
  't': 1.00
  # z: 0.00
}
```

I tried to apply this directly using:

```
dataframe['Genome'].apply(lambda bps: pd.Series([lookup[bp] if bp in lookup else 0.0 for bp in bps.lower()])).values
```

But I have too much data to fit into memory so I'm trying to process using chunks and I'm having trouble defining a reprocessing function.

Here's my code so far:

```
lookup = {
  'a': 0.25,
  'g': 0.50,
  'c': 0.75,
  't': 1.00
  # z: 0.00
}


dfpath = 'C:\\Users\\CAAVR\\Desktop\\Ison.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(dfpath, chunksize=10)

chunk_list = []
def preprocess(chunk):
  chunk['Genome'].apply(lambda bps: pd.Series([lookup[bp] if bp in lookup else 0.0 for bp in bps.lower()])).values
  return;


for chunk in dataframe:
  chunk_filter = preprocess(chunk)
  chunk_list.append(chunk_filter)
  dataframe1 = pd.concat(chunk_list)

print(dataframe1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `chunk_filter = preprocess(chunk)`, but your `preprocess()` function returns nothing, so `chunk_filter` is always meaningless. Modify your preprocess function to store the result of the `apply()` call, then return that value. For example:

```
def preprocess(chunk):
  processed_chunk = chunk['Genome'].apply(lambda bps: pd.Series([lookup[bp] if bp in lookup else 0.0 for bp in bps.lower()])).values
  return processed_chunk;
```

By doing this, you actually return the data from the preprocess function so that it can be appended to the chunk list. As you have it currently, the preprocess function works correctly but essentially discards the results.